# How to keep selected points on a ColumnDataSource object and deselect them with ResetTool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I have plotted a circle glyph. When I select some points they are marked as selected. But I lose the selection when I change the tool I am using or when I click on some other place of the figure. Which is the best way to keep the selection on the circle glyph?. I want to deselect all the points when the `ResetTool` is pressed. I am working with the master (`0.12.14+25.g675aacf72`) branch of bokeh where the `Selection` class already exists.

```
def update_selection(self, attr, old, new):
    ''' I do this to avoid deselection '''
    if new.indices == []:
        self.source.selected.indices = self.old_selection
    else:            
        self.old_selection = list(new.indices)

source.on_change(
    'selected',
    update_selection
)
```

I use this to call a callback when the Reset tool is pressed:

```
def deselect_points(self, event):
    ''' I do this to deselect point on Reset event
        But when the indices are updated the update_selection method is called
    '''
    self.source.selected.indices = []

plot.on_event(Reset, deselect_points)
```

So is there a way to keep the selection and only deselect point on Reset event?

### Update 03/14/2018

This is happening only when the Tap Tool is enabled. So I have written an [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7627) on GitHub to check if this is the expected behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made a workaround like this:

```python
# [...]

self.reset_selection = False

# [...]

def _reset_lines(self, event):
    # hide the glyphs which mark the selected points
    self.lr.visible = False
    self.lr_circle_selected.visible = False
    self.lr.data_source.data = self.empty_source.data
    self.lr_circle_selected.view = self.empty_view

    self.reset_selection = True

def update_selection(self, attr, old, new):
    if new.indices == []:
        if not self.reset_selection:
            new.indices = list(self.selection)    # keep the selection
        else:
            self.reset_selection = False
            self.selection = []
    else:
        self.selection = list(new.indices)

self.plot.on_event(Reset, self._reset_lines)
```

So I am going to use this in the mean time I don´t find anything better

### Update

It seems that [the issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7627) is already closed. So I hope this is solved already